# Could not connect to smtp Outlook.com server

Tags: mutt

I can't force mutt to send mail to the Outlook.com SMTP server, my config is as follows:

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://$imap_user@smtp-mail.outlook.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "mysecretpassword"
set ssl_force_tls = yes
```

I always get the message that SASL authentication failed.

The same configuration (username, password, server, port) works well when used by `msmtp`.

```
set sendmail="msmtp"
```

and msmtp config:

```
account cs-outlook
tls on
tls_certcheck off
host smtp-mail.outlook.com
port 587
from myuser@outlook.com 
auth on
user myuser@outlook.com
password mysecretpassword

account default : cs-outlook
```

It looks like a some kind of bug in mutt, but I'm not sure - perhaps some additional configuration is missing?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer using the "Answer your question" button below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in `mutt`. The package `mutt-patched` from debian repository works fine with this settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing $imap_user with myuser@outlook.com (set smtp_url = "smtp://myuser@outlook.com@smtp-mail.outlook.com:587/")? smtp_url can manage multiple @s (it can still distinguish user name from server name). It's what works for me in a very similar Exchange configuration.

Comment: I tried this approach, but it didn't help.